# Regex to match first n characters of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am creating a regex to query a MySQL database dynamically based on some text. I have the text parsed, and now I need to make a regex based off of the text that will match a string that contains the first N characters of the text with a minimum of 3 characters. So far I am doing this:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^' + text.substr(0, 3).replace(/[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g, '\\$&'));
```

That works to make sure the first three characters match, but then I want to query the database to see if there are any matches for the rest of the text. For example, if the text was 'test string', I want to make a regex that will match columns in the database with values such as 'tes', 'test str', 'test string', etc. only up to as far as the text goes.

I wasn't really sure how to word the title, so hopefully I did not miss any similiar questions. If there is a better way to query the database for this, I am open to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain MySQL you could write:

```
select * from table where column like concat(left(@YOUR_INPUT, 3),  '%') and instr(@YOUR_INPUT, column);
```

where @YOUR_INPUT would be the full text value you have in hand (whether you pass it as a parameter [which is the proper way :) ] to the query or you put it in a MySQL variable).

edited: Added a clause to ensure that only matches the strings that are contained within the input and not the others

Comment: But doesn't this allow strings like 'test stringggg' or 'tesfoo' to pass where they shouldn't in my example? In my example, 'tes', 'test string', and 'test str' pass because they are strings that are entirely in the original text from the left.

Comment: You are right, I missed half the point. I edited the query so it makes the trick (I think at least!). But I worked my way without a regex, I just added another clause that ensures that the value of the column is contained within the string. Is this the expected behaviour?